# Clipping a GEE Image with the Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, clip, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am looking for a way to clip image collection by a given polygon geometry with Python API,

The GEE JavaScript equivalent is simply `ImageCollection.clip(geom)`
(https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_visualization#clipping)

With the python API I get the **error**: `'ImageCollection' object has no attribute 'clip'.`

---

I'm adding my code after using `.mean()` as a reducer

```py
# set the boundary polygon
my_boundary = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
[[-5, 40],[65, 40],[65, 60],[-5, 60],[-5, 60]]]
,proj=None)

#set the ImageCollection and Image
img_Collection = (ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/NRTI/L3_NO2')
                  .filterDate('2020-03-01', '2020-03-27')
                  .select('NO2_column_number_density'))

my_Image=img_Collection.mean().clip(my_boundary)

#Create Ipyleaflet map
my_map = ipyleaflet.Map(zoom=7)
my_map.add_layer(layer=my_Image)

my_map
```

`**error:** AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'model_id'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No matter the API, `clip()` [is a function on **images**](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.image.clip), but not **image collections**. So in order to do it, you have to either turn your `ImageCollection` into an `Image` using reducers like `mean()`, `mosaic()` etc. or `map` clipping procedure over your `ImageCollection`, i.e.

`imageCollection.map(function(image) { return image.clip(geometry); });`

In pyhton API, use [lambda function](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/python_install#syntax) in such case.

Comment: Basile, thanks for the comment. I used the `mean()` reducer and then `clip()` . I now turned the **ImageCollection** into **Image** like you advised.  Now when I add layer to my map I'm getting: _" AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'model_id' "_

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code

Comment: I added my code to my question

Comment: @Ofir I made an example with `IPython.display` which shows that the image is clipped as expected, and thus, the problem is related to ipyleaflet rendering, which is a separate matter. Here's the [link to Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KgUoCcG1kmW4FKJ6zBchtUp1w6hcCJC8)

Comment: I guess it's more complicated or unsupported with Ipyleaflet (in Jupyter). I ran the same code using the Qgis EarthEnngine plugin and it worked also. I learned alot from this problem, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Just to add the Python code to Basile's answer:

```
collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2") \
.filterBounds(aoi) 

clipped = collection.map(lambda image: image.clip(aoi))
```