# Clipping a data set using a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, clip

I am using the OREGONSTATE_PRISM_Norm81m data set on Google Earth Engine and I am trying to clip the data to only Washington State. I uploaded a shapefile from the Washington Department of Natural Resource GIS Open Data. This is the code I currently have, I only have added the shapefile and changed the map center from the original data.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('OREGONSTATE/PRISM/AN81d')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-08-01', '2018-08-15'));
var precipitation = dataset.select('ppt');
var precipitationVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 50.0,
  palette: ['red', 'yellow', 'green', 'cyan', 'purple'],
};

var state = table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('JURISDIC_3', 'Washington State'));
var rain = precipitation.clip(state);

Map.setCenter(-120.332, 47.448, 7);
Map.addLayer(precipitation, precipitationVis, 'Precipitation');
Map.addLayer(table);
```

The error message states that `"precipitation.clip is not a function"` and I am very confused because I have used a similar code several times before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clipping a GEE Image with Python API](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/356588/clipping-a-gee-image-with-python-api)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code. `precipitation` is an `ee.ImageCollection`, and doesn't have a `clip()` method. Depending on what you're trying to do, you can either reduce `precipitation`, so you get a single `ee.Image` to clip, or or you map over `precipitation`, and clip each individual image in the collection. The second problem is having `state` being an argument to `clip()`. You have not included the definition of `table`, but by the look of it, it's an `ee.FeatureCollection`, which means `state` is also an `ee.FeatureCollection`. `clip()` takes an `ee.Geometry` as an argument. You can easily extract the geometry: `state.geometry()`

So, either you do something like this, to turn precipitation into an `ee.Image`, then clip it:

```
var rain = precipitation
  .median()
  .clip(state.geometry());
```

or you clip every image in the `precipitation` collection:

```
var rain = precipitation
  .map(function (image) {
    return image.clip(state.geometry())
  });
```